# Xamarin Forms,maps получить карту местности текущего пользователя и показать на карте вновь подключившихся с учётом его координат

Tags: c#, xamarin, карты, forms

Как  в Xamarin Forms получить карту местности текущего пользователя и при подключении другого пользователя увидеть его на карте с его же координатами нахождения

Comment: На этом ресурсе задают вопросы и отвечают на них. Задачи же ставят и оплачивают их исполнение на др.ресурсах.

Answer (score 0):

берете реализацию карты с маркерами тут:
https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-maps/
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithMaps/

Пишите [серверную часть](https://www.asp.net/web-api). 
отправлете на сервер свои координаты (другие пользователи делают то же самое). На сервере работает [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr). он отправляет рассылку о координатах пользователей. Вы на нее подписываетесь и показываете других на своем устройстве. все.